# unable to instantiate an object of TimerTask class

Tags: android

I am trying to create two timers each one with a new timerTask as shown in te code below. the timerTask object is an object of the class Timedtask3.
eclipse underscores the "new Timedtask3()" with red, lease see the lines ended with "//error" below.

the error says "No enclosing instance of type TimerTask00 is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type TimerTask00 (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance 
of TimerTask00)."

how to fix this error?

**Code**:

```
public class TimerTask00 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new Timedtask3(), 5000);//error

    timer.cancel();
    timer.purge();

    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new Timedtask3(), 5000);//error
    }

    class Timedtask3 extends TimerTask {

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("timer 3");
    }
};
}
```

Comment: ur Timedtask3 should be static as far as I know. since you are directly using an inner class in a static method (main)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make you `Timedtask3`  class to be `static`, e.g.

```
static class Timedtask3 extends TimerTask {...}
```

this should get rid of the immediate problem.

you can't instantiate a `non static inner class` within a `static method`.

Answer (score 0):

//From YouTube "Java Full Course" by Bro Code - "an easy implementation of the
//timertask is to add an anonymous class... add unimplemented methods (run) ...

```
TimerTask mbTTask = new TimerTask(){
@Override
public void run(){
    System.out.println("Task is complete.");
}
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! This question already has an accepted answer. Your answer does not seem to add anything new.